# Filling profile forms with data from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sorry for the green questions, I'm completely new to Facebook integration.

If I have a site with a fairly lengthy profile form, (e.g. gender, age, etc) is it possible to extract this information from Facebook, rather than getting the user to fill it in from scratch?

If I want my site to get a user's social graph from Facebook, so it can show what their friend's are doing / etc on my site, is this allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`users.getInfo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo) function to see what user profile options you can get :)

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz. There seems to be a hell of a lot of information you can access using that function. Are you allowed to extract the whole lot and save it into your own database (with the user's permission)? Are there restrictions in the Ts & Cs about that?

Comment: @Harry: Yes according to  new policy, you can not use/get that data outside of facebook/app. You can use it with your app but can not share it.